# PAM exec stdout issue

Tags: debian, python, pam

I am having an issue with a dead simple python script; called with pam_exec.

I added a line at the end of that file `/etc/pam.d/common-session` :

> session optional pam_exec.so /bin/python /usr/local/bin/pam_notify_python.py

The `pam_notify_python.py` script contains a simple `print "Hello world"`

Obviously, this is not working, but I do not understand why. The script is not printing anything when I `su user` or simply `su`, but when I start a new shell and manually execute `python /usr/local/bin/pam_notify_python.py` it is working.

Did I miss something ?
Thanks for reading !

Answer (score 1):

The `pam_exec(8)` man page tells why:

```
       stdout
           Per default the output of the executed command is written to
           /dev/null. With this option, the stdout output of the executed
           command is redirected to the calling application. It's in the
           responsibility of this application what happens with the output.
           The log option is ignored.
```

So you need to add `stdout` to the line:

```
session optional pam_exec.so stdout /bin/python /usr/local/bin/pam_notify_python.py
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I forgot to say that, indeed, I finally added the `stdout` statement but it outputs (when I try a `print` in python or a `echo` in bash) : `stdout failed: exit code 2`. But it still works when i manually call the script. Weird.

Comment: @Loris1634: A patch to add this and another feature appears to have been added to Fedora, but [not yet to Debian](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=670147).

Comment: Thank you, then I will wait for a patch for Debian. Another weird thing with `pam_exec` is when I do like this in my script : `variable = $(ldapsearch .....) and then echo "output : $variable" >> /path/to/a/file` , the content of the file is : `output : `. But when I run my command from the shell then it outputs something. Everything `echo` related is not working I guess.

Comment: I found `pam_script` here: https://github.com/jeroennijhof/pam_script/blob/master/Makefile.am but same issue.